# One-icon way to play a video with repeat on IPad

Tags: video, ipados

I don't know if [guided access](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/guided-access-ipada16d1374/ipados) could help, but I specifically don't want a  toddler to have to choose videos. I do want an easy way to let them loop a specific video. There should just be an icon to press (the image ideally somehow selectable by me, but if it's chosen automatically from the video in some smart way, that can also work) and that's it.

Is there an easy way for me to arrange that on iOS 16 on an iPad?

Answer (score 0):

I would get the [VLC Media Player](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/vlc-media-player/id650377962) and only load the one video you need. Then I would use Guided Access to restrict that app before handing the device to the toddler.

It's not perfect and the app might be too complicated, but once you've learned how that works, you might ask a follow on question for app recommendations once you see how one specific app works for you.

Also, don't underestimate your toddler. They learn tech quickly and can navigate the Home Screen - especially if you have widgets for the video files they need added to the Home Screen. Guided access is 100% the way I would start though - lock them in one app alone. They can learn the repeat, play function of one app if the content is appealing enough and boredom is just around the corner if they don't master the interface for your chosen player.